# How to add dynamic button under another view?

Tags: android

In android, I have a block of code:

```
// RelativeLayout with id is "root": main.xml
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/pref_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:hint="Text to share in preference"
/>
// This is the button I want to add to main.xml
 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/save_button"
    android:layout_below="@id/pref_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save"
/>
```

In my activity, With `RelativeLayout.LayoutParam` I can add the `button` in the position `left, right, top, bottom` of `root` view, but I can't add `below` or etc... of another view!! 
So, Anyone could give a suggestion to add a `view` which relates with another `view` in `RelativeLayout` dynamically ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go.  This will accomplish what you are looking to do:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
private RelativeLayout rl;
private EditText editText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

    rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_rl);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pref_edit_text);

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("Save");

    // create the layout params that will be used to define how your
    // button will be displayed
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // add the rule that places your button below your EditText object
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, editText.getId());

    // set the layoutParams on the button
    button.setLayoutParams(params);

    // add button to your RelativeLayout
    rl.addView(button);
}
}
```

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc can you please guide how can i place the multtiple dynamic buttons with random position in a relative layouts